# Eclipse Tycho not able to resolve the correct dependency

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho

I am utilizing Eclipse Tycho to build my RCP application with GMF dependencies.

I am getting the following error -

```
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not download artifacts from any repository
[ERROR] osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.emf.core,1.4.1.v20120514-1615
[ERROR] osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.emf.commands.core,1.4.0.v20120514-1615
[ERROR] osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.emf.ui.properties,1.5.0.v20120514-1615
[ERROR] osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui,1.6.0.v20120514-1615
[ERROR] osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.properties,1.4.2.v20120514-1615
[ERROR] osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.providers,1.5.0.v20120514-1615
[ERROR] osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.providers.ide,1.2.0.v20120514-1615
[ERROR] osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.render,1.6.0.v20120514-1615
[ERROR] osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.resources.editor,1.4.1.v20120514-1615
[ERROR] osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.resources.editor.ide,1.2.1.v20120514-1615
```

I am specifing the following dependency in the Manifest.MF -

```
org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.emf.core;bundle-version="1.4.1",
 org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.emf.commands.core;bundle-version="1.4.0",
 org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.emf.ui.properties;bundle-version="1.5.0",
 org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui;bundle-version="1.6.0",
 org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.properties;bundle-version="1.4.2",
 org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.providers;bundle-version="1.5.0",
 org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.providers.ide;bundle-version="1.2.0",
 org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.render;bundle-version="1.6.0",
 org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.lite.svg;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.resources.editor;bundle-version="1.4.1",
 org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.resources.editor.ide;bundle-version="1.2.1",
```

I have provided the repository location for GMF bundle as -

```
<repository>
  <id>gmf-runtime</id>
  <url>http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/gmp/gmf-runtime/updates/releases</url>
  <layout>p2</layout>
</repository>
```

The P2 repository has all the above JAR's. The only difference is that for some reason Tycho is looking for **.v20120514-1615** qualifier. However the P2 repository has **.201302191707** qualifier. Not sure why Tycho is looking for that specific qualifier and not resolve to the latest version.

Comment: It seems that the .v20120514-1615 versions are also in your target platform. Some other p2 repository you have configured seems to contain the gmf installable units (see content.jar/content.xml) but not the corresponding artifacts.

Comment: @oberlies : Just wondering if there is any way to trace the P2 repo which has that installable unit? A maven/tycho debug flag maybe?

Comment: `-Dtycho.debug.resolver=true` prints out all IUs in the [target platform](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform#Effective_content_of_the_target_platform), but AFAIK it doesn't say which p2 repositories the content comes from. Feel free to open an [enhancement request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Tycho) for this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the original P2 Repo was corrupted. The problem is that Tycho tries to index the whole P2 repo even if the Plugins are not referenced. To solve this what did was -

1. Open .product file and export the product
2. Copy the 'repository' folder from the exported product artifacts and place it in a shared location
3. In the  tag in Maven pom.xml give the location of this repository instead if external repositories. All the future Tycho builds will use this repository

This way the repo size is small and all the build issues are resolved.

Comment: Do you mean "Tycho tries to index the whole P2 repo even if the _.jars_ are not referenced" ?

Comment: @PaulVerest : Unfortunately yes. But indexing essentially means it checks the content.jar file from the P2 repo and sees if everything can be resolved. Everything works fine as long as the P2 repo is correctly setup. The best way I found was to mirror the repos on our own servers(maybe there is a better way).